# Value returned as a string

Tags: javascript

I am only beggining my journey with Java Script! I was trying to create an input where I type in a number and after I press a button it would add the value to the var a = 0;

With the script I have written it returns the value as a string. Any ideas on how to make the value of the input be returned as a number? Thanks!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JAVASCRIPT PRACTISE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="payment">

</div>
<button onclick="addToBal(10)" name="button">add 10 bucks</button>
<button onclick="subFromBal(10)" name="button">pay 10 bucks</button><br><br>

<input type="text" id="addInput" value="">
<button type="button" id="addSubmit" onclick="addValue()">add this amount of bucks</button>

    <script>
    var a = 0;
    function addToBal(amtAdded) {
      a += amtAdded;
      document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
    };
    function subFromBal(amtSubstracted) {
      a -= amtSubstracted;
      document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
    }; //THATS THE END OF THAT SECTION

    function addValue(value) {
      a += document.getElementById("addInput").value;
      document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
    };

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.value` always returns a string, you must convert it to a number.

Comment: `a += Number(document.getElementById("addInput").value);`

Answer (score 1):

Input values are of type *string*. That's why string concatenation is happening. You have to convert the value to number to perform arithmetic operation. You can use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or prefix the value with `+` to convert the string value to number:

```js
var a = 0;
function addToBal(amtAdded) {
  a += amtAdded;
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
};
function subFromBal(amtSubstracted) {
  a -= amtSubstracted;
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
}; //THATS THE END OF THAT SECTION

function addValue(value) {
  a += Number(document.getElementById("addInput").value);
  //OR: using +
  //a += +document.getElementById("addInput").value;
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
};
```

```html
<div id="payment">

</div>
<button onclick="addToBal(10)" name="button">add 10 bucks</button>
<button onclick="subFromBal(10)" name="button">pay 10 bucks</button><br><br>

<input type="text" id="addInput" value="">
<button type="button" id="addSubmit" onclick="addValue()">add this amount of bucks</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with:

`document.getElementById("addInput").value;`

This will return a string, meaning that when you add it, it will concatenate (glue) it to `a` (as an int+string gives a string), not *add* which is what you're after.

Thus, you can simply convert this string to a number by putting a `+` in front of it:

`+document.getElementById("addInput").value;`

See working example below:

```js
var a = 0;

function addToBal(amtAdded) {
  a += amtAdded;
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
};

function subFromBal(amtSubstracted) {
  a -= amtSubstracted;
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
};

function addValue(value) {
  a += +document.getElementById("addInput").value; // Add + here to convert string to number (ie: int, float etc)
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = a;
};
```

```html
<div id="payment"></div>

<button onclick="addToBal(10)" name="button">add 10 bucks</button>
<button onclick="subFromBal(10)" name="button">pay 10 bucks</button><br><br>

<input type="text" id="addInput" value="">
<button type="button" id="addSubmit" onclick="addValue()">add this amount of bucks</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number()`

[reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

```
var num = "10";
num = Number(num); // 10 not "10"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parseInt(document.getElementById("addInput").value)` which will convert the string as integer.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should understand about the string + number in JS.

[http://jslearning.info/javascript-numbers/](http://%20http://jslearning.info/javascript-numbers/)

You can only +/- 2 number, JS will convert to number.
you should not use Number in JS because it cause the speed in JS.
One more thing, if you HTML5, we can use input type is number

```
<input type="number" name="number">
```